# Cannot SSH through VPN (Windows 8, Cisco Client), but ping works, and SSH from other machines works too

Tags: ssh, windows-8.1, vpn, ubuntu-14.04, cisco-vpn-client

On my Ubuntu Linux workstation, I have a properly working SSH server. I can log on to this machine from other machines in the same (physical) network.

My goal is to log on to this workstation from my Windows 8.1 laptop, which is *not* connected to the same network. From my laptop, I can log on to my University's VPN using a Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client. This seems to work in general. I can also `ping` to my workstation, after setting up the VPN connection. Note that I am sure I'm pinging the right computer (thus ruling out IP conflicts or so), since when I monitor incoming ICMP requests there, the pings from my Windows machine are coming through.

Now the problem is that SSH (using Putty) through the tunnel does not seem to work. Putty keeps giving me "Network error: Connection timed out".

The SSH server is listening on both IPv4 and IPv6:

```
eelke@eelkebox:/var/log$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep ssh
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21436/sshd      
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      21436/sshd
```

(The Cisco client is (I think) configured to drop all IPv6 traffic, that's why I checked that IPv4 connections were also allowed.)

There also is no firewall running:

```
eelke@eelkebox:/var/log$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

Any ideas on how to get my Windows laptop to connect to the SSH server through the VPN?

Comment: You're connecting to a University network? Do they block external SSH port connections?

Comment: @BigChris There's no mention of this anywhere on the intranet. Also, the purpose of setting up a VPN in the first place would be specifically to *allow* connections to such services, right? (BTW I also tried running the SSH server on port 33567, so it's definitely not a port 22-specific block.)

Comment: Enterprises do things people often don't expect... I work for a University IT dept. and many services are blocked even though I can VPN in. The fact you've VPN'ed in has probably put you onto a specific VLAN which has routes to your office VLAN, and then the VPN VLAN may have ports blocked to prevent the network being opened to attack from unknown "home computers".

Comment: You don't need to move SSH server to other ports. You can start a TCP server using `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`. It will start an HTTP server at port 8000. You can change the port by giving port number as parameter. You can use that to verify incoming TCP connection.

Comment: @someuser I prefer the nc command i install it with cygwin.  Python keep changing it how to set up their http server ,  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server  it used to be SimpleHTTPServer now it is http.server

Answer (score 0):

A quick test to check if the port is available is to try to telnet to it. If successful then you should see something like this

```
# telnet 127.0.0.1 22
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.1
```

Otherwise it could be a firewall, somewhere along the route, blocking.